# Android Data Binding: how to pass variable to include layout

Tags: android-databinding

Google documentation says that variables may be passed into an included layout's binding from the containing layout but I can't make it work but get data binding error ****msg:Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. handler is missing it. 
The including XML looks like this:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>
    <import type="com.example.FocusChangeHandler"/>

    <variable
        name="handler"
        type="FocusChangeHandler"/>
</data>

<!-- Some other views  --->

   <include
            android:id="@+id/inputs"
            layout="@layout/input_fields"
            bind:handler="@{handler}"/>        
</layout>
```

And the included XML like this:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/nameEdit"       
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
   android:onFocusChange="@{handler.onFocusChange}"/>
</layout>
```

I'm able to refer the Views from included layout through generated binding class but passing a variable just doesn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html) specifies

> Here, there must be a user variable in both the name.xml and
>   contact.xml layout files

I assume you should have this in your included layout:

```
    <data>
           <variable name="handler"
                     type="FocusChangeHandler"/>
    </data>
```

Comment: Funny but I already tried this when I was playing with it and got an error about variable being defined multiple times. Something must have been changed between Android Studio 2.0 Beta 3 and Beta 5 as it seems to work now.

Comment: Is it possible to pass multiple variables? I've tried:
`<variable name="onClick" type="android.view.View.OnClickListener"/>
        <variable name="buttonText" type="String"/>`
but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 25):

> Just create `<variable` for passing values to included layouts.
>
> Like **`app:passedText="@{@string/app_name}"`**

### Example

Like I want to pass `String` to included layout. I will create a variable of type `String`. Refer that `String` to your `TextView`. I created `passedText` for example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <data>
        // declare fields
        <variable
            name="passedText"
            type="String"/>
    </data>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{passedText}"/> //set field to your view.

</layout>
```

Now add `passedText` field to your `<include` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <include
            layout="@layout/layout_common"
            app:passedText="@{@string/app_name}" // here we pass any String 
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**Note that both layouts (parent & included) should be `binding layout`, wrapped with `<layout`**

Comment: Remember to call `DataBindingUtil.setContentView<FragmentOfferDetailBinding>(this, R.layout.fragment_offer_detail)`, EVEN if you're not using any of its elements.

Comment: @DelacrixMorgan See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51633632/6891563, please don't use `DataBindingUtil` for Fragments & Dialogs.

Comment: Simple and crisp!

Comment: @CosmicDev yes you can take multiple strings variables, there is no limit.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Is there anything else im missing except for these 2 code snippets? Do fragments (kotlin) files need something extra?

Comment: @Patrick please read full answer, it will work. It is working solution.

Answer (score 9):

For hardcoded string:

```
 android:label="@{`Test 123`}"
```

Comment: Not working for me. attribute not found